# Why this DropDownList is not updating inside this GridView?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

And I have a GridView that I am using it to add, delete and update/edit the employees information. This information is employee Username, Name, BadgeNo, JobTitle, IsActive and the DivisionShortcut. The Divisions will be listed in DropDownList. I wrote the code but I got the following error:
*

> Invalid column name 'DivisionShortcut'.

- ASP.NET Code:

  ```
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"></asp:DropDownList>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                  SortExpression="Username" />

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("Name")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                    Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") %>'/>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB" runat="Server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </span>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 

          SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.IsActive
                          FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode"
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employee], [Divisions] SET [Name] = @Name, [JobTitle] = @JobTitle, 
                                              [BadgeNo] = @BadgeNo, [DivisionShortcut] = @division WHERE [Username] = @Username"
          DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [employee] WHERE [Username] = @Username">
          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String"  />
              <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNo" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionShortcut" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
          </UpdateParameters>
          <DeleteParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
          </DeleteParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
  ```

I forgot to mention that there is a SqlDataSource for the DropDownList.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DivisionsListDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Divisions">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    //For editing any row in the GridView
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }

    //For updating the information in any row in the GridView
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            DropDownList DivisionsList = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DivisionsList"); 

            TextBox txtEmployeeName = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtEmployeeName");
            TextBox txtJobTitle = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtJobTitle");
            TextBox txtBadgeNo = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtBadgeNo");

            CheckBox isActive = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("isActive");

            //For getting the ID (primary key) of that row
            string username = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            string name = txtEmployeeName.Text;
            string jobTitle = txtJobTitle.Text;
            string badgeNo = txtBadgeNo.Text;
            string division = DivisionsList.SelectedValue.ToString();

            UpdateEmployeeInfo(username, name, jobTitle, badgeNo, division);
        }
private void UpdateEmployeeInfo(string username, string name, string jobTitle, string badgeNo, string division)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                                                BadgeNo = @BadgeNo, DivisionShortcut = @division
                            WHERE Username = @Username";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", badgeNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", division);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isActive.checked);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            //            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
            //                                                BadgeNo = @BadgeNo 
            //                                                WHERE Username = @Username";
            //            SqlDataSource1.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And the error is:
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'DivisionShortcut'.*

which is fired in the Catch block from the UpdateEmployeeInfo()

**UPDATE 2:**

The update query for the DivisionShortcut will like the following:

```
UPDATE Divisions SET [DivisionShortcut] = @division WHERE SapCode = @SapCode
```

**But how it will be updated?**

Comment: Where is DataSource with ID DivisionsListDataSource?

Comment: where is DivisionsListDataSource sqldatasource ?

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I forgot to put the complete code for you here.

Comment: DivisionsListDataSource is present inside the gridview ?

Comment: No, it is ouside the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column "DivisionShortcut" is present in the table Divisions.
and you are updating it in employees table due to which the error occured.
Please remove the column `DivisionShortcut` from this update query

```
string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                                            BadgeNo = @BadgeNo, DivisionShortcut =  @division
                        WHERE Username = @Username";
```

And write an other update query to update DivisionShortcut in the Divisions table.

But how it will be updated ? You have to call this query the same way you called the Update Employee. Or you can put both the query in the same update command.

```
string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
BadgeNo = @BadgeNo, DivisionShortcut = @division WHERE Username = @Username; 
UPDATE Divisions SET [DivisionShortcut] = @division WHERE SapCode = @SapCode;"
```

**Updated Answer:**
Error: `The error is: Must declare the scalar variable "@SapCode"`
Add a new parameter to your command object like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SapCode", sapcode);
```

**Again Updated Answer:**

```
string query = "Select sapcode from Divisons where Divison.DivisonCode = Employees.DivisonCode"
```

To get the latest Division code from the employees table you can use the sql server **ScopeIdentity()** function.

Comment: Ok writing a query for updating a division is easy and it will be like the one shown in my updated question. But how it will be updated?

Comment: @Wagar Janjua, Thank you for your continuous help. However, now I got an error that I don't know how to solve it. **The error is: Must declare the scalar variable "@SapCode"**.

Comment: see my updated answer. You have to add a new parameter to your command object. Like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SapCode", sapcode);`

Comment: Yeah, but how I will be able to get the SapCode value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13715/discussion-between-waqar-janjua-and-tech-lover)

Comment: from the database. Is there any relationship b/w the two tables ?

Comment: Yeah, as you see in my question above, there is a relationship since the DivisionCode is foreign key to the SapCode.

Comment: come in discussion room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13715/discussion-between-waqar-janjua-and-tech-lover

Comment: It is blocked because I am using the company Internet. Sorry for that.

Comment: no prob. then write a query to get sap code. `string query = "Select sapcode from Divisons where Divison.DivisonCode = Employees.DivisonCode"` To get the latest Division code from the employees table you can use the sql server ScopeIdentity() function. and remember to voteup and mark this as your answer. If you still have any question plz ask.

Comment: I don't know how to use ScopeIdentity(), but anyway thanks for your continuous help. I am gonna try to solve it.

Comment: divison code is automatically genrated key or you are inserting in the employees table ? if you are inserting then you do not need to use scopeidentity() function. ScopeIdentity() is used to return the automatically genrated key.

Comment: Dear Waqar, In Divisions table, I have all the SapCodes for all the divisions. In Employee table, I have DivisionCode which is a foreign key to the SapCode in the employee table. I have a GridView that shows all the employees with their information. For the division, I put a dropdownlist to show all the divisions and the user will just select the division. DropDownList has its SqlDataSource that binds it to the Divisions table. But the GridView binds to the Employees table.

Comment: This is the situation that I am struggling with it.

Comment: GV is showing the emp's record, dropdown is showing all the dvisions now what's the problem ? What do you want to do now ?

Comment: do you want to update Divison in the employee's Table ? If yes then select the Divison from the dropdownlist. Like `string divison = DropDownList.Text ` after getting the divison pass it as parameter to the command object as I show you earlier.